# Resizing a table-layout: fixed table in Safari?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari

Here's a CodePen: https://codepen.io/neezer/pen/eWvLrm

---

1. Load that pen in Chrome (I'm running 57.0.2987.133).
2. Change the width of the `<table>` to `150px` using a style attribute. Don't do this in the code (as it will cause a refresh--that's specific to CodePen and not my issue), but instead change it programmatically through the console or in the web inspector.

Note how Chrome resizes the table and does the proper overflow for the `td`/`th` elements:

[image: chrome]

---

1. Load that pen in Safari (I'm running 10.1 (12603.1.30.0.34)).
2. Change the width of the `<table>` to `150px` using a style attribute. Don't do this in the code (as it will cause a refresh--that's specific to CodePen and not my issue), but instead change it programmatically through the console or in the web inspector.

Note how Safari ***does not*** resize the table to the given dimensions, since the `td`/`th` do not appear to shrink smaller than their content.

[image: safari]

---

Why is this different? The only explanation I can think of is that Safari does not repaint the table on style changes, taking `table-layout` into account. I found [this in the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout):

> Under the "fixed" layout method, the entire table can be rendered once
>   the first table row has been downloaded and analyzed. This can speed
>   up rendering time over the "automatic" layout method, but subsequent
>   cell content may not fit in the column widths provided. **Any cell that
>   has content that overflows uses the overflow property to determine
>   whether to clip the overflow content, but only if the table has a
>   known width, otherwise it won't overflow the cells.**

The difference to me seems that Chrome re-evaluates the table when it detects a dimension change on the `<table>`, but Safari does not, and thus does not overflow the cell.

I can make this problem go away if I ensure that `<table>` has a set width ***on initial render***, but that's a no-go for my app, which allows the user to dynamically resize table dimensions. Needless to say, it works great in Chrome but not Safari.

Is there anyway to have Safari behave like Chrome here? Some way to force Safari to do the re-evaluation, if that is what's actually happening here?
 Do Firefox/IE/Edge suffer from the same problem? Could they benefit from the same solution?

---

***UPDATE***: This little experiment in Safari's web inspector seems to confirm my theory: http://d.pr/v/bzhIH

Comment: How do users resize the table? Is it possible to toggle the table to `table-layout: auto` and then back to `table-layout: fixed` when the new value is set?

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your `<table>` in `<div>`, set table width to this `<div>` and `width: 100%;` to the `<table>`.

If you want stretch your `<table>` for the columns content width, you need to replace `width: 100%;` from `<table>` and set `width: auto;` to `<div>`.

Here's example: https://codepen.io/Izumenko/pen/zaGGRM